# Java Arrays.fill() function executes prematurely on main thread?

Tags: java, android, arrays, passwords

This code is under a button's OnClickListner

```
String username = edtLabel.getText().toString():
char[] password = new char[edtPassword.getText().length()];
edtPassword.getText().getChars(0, edtPassword.getText().length(), password,0);

new BackGroundTask(username, password).execute();
Arrays.fill(password, '0');
```

The problem I am facing here is that the password passed to the BackGroundTask constructor(an AsyncTask class) is always an array of zeros that is {0, 0, 0}. Although I call Arrays.fill() function after the setting up the constructor.

The code is a bit longer than the given snippet, validating several other things but does not alter password at any point of time.

I have been looking everywhere for quite sometime but could not find anything.
Only solution I see is using a Handler which executes after a few hundred milliseconds which fills the passwords with zeros.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        Arrays.fill(password, '0');
    }
 }, 100);
```

Any better and straight forward technique would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to execute `Arrays.fill(password, '0');` after 
 `BackGroundTask` completion?

Comment: A background task executes in paralle with the current thread. So the line of code following its invocation can execute in parallel with, or even before, the task. If you don't want that, don't use the feature.

Comment: Yes, or after the Constructor accepts it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `BackGroundTask` constructor is not supposed to alter the original `password` array, you can pass a copy of that array using `Arrays.copyOf()`.

```
char[] pwCopy = Arrays.copyOf(password,password.length);
new BackGroundTask(username, pwCopy).execute();
Arrays.fill(password, '0');
```

EDIT: If the goal is to remove the password from memory after you are done using it, I'd move the `Arrays.fill(password, '0');` call to the end of the method (or constructor) of the `BackGroundTask` class that uses the `password` array. In that case you don't have to create a copy of the array.

Comment: All I want is to discard the password after using it in this LoginActivity

Comment: @Blazing making a copy, as suggested, will solve your problem. An alternative would be to call Arrays.fill at the end of the `BackGroundTask` constructor (only if the `execute()` method doesn't require the original content of that array).

Comment: this does not solve the problem. The pwCopy still holds the password in the memory.

Comment: @Blazing in that case, let the consumer of that password (the `BackGroundTask` constructor or the `BackGroundTask`'s `execute` method fill the array with 0s once it's done using it.

Comment: Does that dispose off the password array in the LoginActivity too? I heard java is pass by value

Comment: @Blazing Java passes a reference to the array by value. If you don't create a copy of the array, there's only one array instance, so modifying it in one place (either the LoginActivity or the BackGroundTask class) would affect both classes. After all, you noticed that behavior when you called Arrays.fill() in the Activity and the BackGroundTask saw an array of 0s. Note that I'm talking about modifying the contents of the array, not the array variable. Setting the array variable to `null` in the BackGroundTask constructor won't affect the `password` variable in the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
new BackGroundTask(username, password)
{
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           Arrays.fill(password, '0');
     }

}.execute();
```